# PHP on IIS 8 realm: A username and password are being requested

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have installed **PHP 5.5** on Windows 2012 Server and **IIS 8.0**, as part of a migration from the 2008 servers where everything worked absolutely fine. **Phpinfo()** runs OK, but when I get to run my WordPress sites I get a realm saying: "A username and password are being requested by [MyWebsite]

[image: realm]

Here is my [phpinfo() results](http://wikisend.com/download/754194/phpinfo%28%29.htm)

My [php.ini file](http://wikisend.com/download/203836/php.ini)

**c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config "Default Web Site" /section:anonymousAuthentication** returns:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

**File permissions for (custom) wwwroot folder and files:**

- **Everyone**: RE/L/R
- **Authenticated Users**: Full control
- **IUSR**: Full control
- **System**: Full control
- **Admins**: Full control
- **Users**: RE/L/R
- **IIS_IUSRS**: Full control

My **IIS Authentication configuration:**

[image: IIS Authentication configuration:]

My **Application Pool configuration:**

[image: Application Pool config]

Other PHP websites don't seem to behave correctly as well (displaying only part of the content they should for some reason) but I'm not sure it's the same problem.

All PHP websites connect to a local MySQL server.

Having wasted two days trying to resolve this, I kindly ask for your help on what might be wrong.

Comment: I can't help but notice the message says its coming from your Router... this may have nothing to do with your IIS configuration. Are you trying to connect to your Router on port 80 by mistake?

Comment: I have configured this instance to listen at http://localhost:85, my router's web admin webpage is set to listen on port 8080 of my gateway's IP (192.168.1.254) so this makes things even more weird I guess.

Comment: Update: If I bypass the Load Balancer and hit directly the web server I can access the websites just fine from outside the servers' LAN, however inside the LAN I get this nasty error, which is a problem as the Load Balancer is inside that network, too.